# Pyspark: How to convert a spark dataframe to json and save it as json file?

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to convert my pyspark sql dataframe to json and then save as a file.

```
df_final = df_final.union(join_df)
```

df_final contains the value as such:

[image]

I tried something like this. But it created a invalid json.

```
df_final.coalesce(1).write.format('json').save(data_output_file+"createjson.json", overwrite=True)

{"Variable":"Col1","Min":"20","Max":"30"}
{"Variable":"Col2","Min":"25,"Max":"40"}
```

My expected file should have data as below:

```
[
{"Variable":"Col1",
"Min":"20",
"Max":"30"},
{"Variable":"Col2",
"Min":"25,
"Max":"40"}]
```

Comment: try `df.toJSON()`

Answer (score 9):

For `pyspark` you can directly store your dataframe into json file, there is no need to convert the datafram into json.

```
df_final.coalesce(1).write.format('json').save('/path/file_name.json')
```

and still you want to convert your datafram into json then you can used 
`df_final.toJSON()`.

Comment: Yeah, but it stores data line by line {"Variable":"Col1","Min":"20","Max":"30"}
{"Variable":"Col2","Min":"25,"Max":"40"} instead it should be separated by , and enclosed with square braces

Answer (score 5):

Here is how you can do the equivalent of json.dump for a dataframe with PySpark 1.3+.

```
df_list_of_jsons = df.toJSON().collect()
df_list_of_dicts = [json.loads(x) for x in df_list_of_jsons]
df_json = json.dumps(df_list_of_dicts)
sc.parallelize([df_json]).repartition(1).cache().saveAsTextFile("<HDFS_PATH>")
```

Note this will result in the whole dataframe being loaded into the driver memory, so this is only recommended for small dataframe.

Comment: I tried so many different methods, and this was what finally worked for me. Thank you!!

Answer (score 2):

A solution can be using `collect` and then using `json.dump`:

```
import json
collected_df = df_final.collect()
with open(data_output_file + 'createjson.json', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(data, outfile)
```

Comment: Actually this correct but it is not creating the file directly in hdfs. It creates on the container where the script runs

Comment: It uses driver memory, so it's not recommended.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use spark to process result as json files, I think that your output schema is right in hdfs.

And I assumed you encountered the issue that you can not smoothly read data from normal python script by using :

```
with open('data.json') as f:
  data = json.load(f)
```

You should try to read data line by line:

```
data = []
with open("data.json",'r') as datafile:
  for line in datafile:
    data.append(json.loads(line))
```

and you can use `pandas` to create dataframe :

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Comment: I was trying to understand why there was an answer that was related to reading the json file rather than writing out to it. I understand now, the json format that spark writes out is not comma delimited, and so it must be read back in a little differently. Thank you so much for this

Comment: @FahadAshraf Glad that helped. And yes, the json format that spark writes out is not comma delimited. It's very confuse when reading json file which created from spark (or others hdfs schema) at first time.